# Sort gallery modx

Tags: php, modx

I have albums in modx. I need the images in the album to be sorted by the number in the file name. For example 1-azam, 2-azam..34-azam. How to sort before passing to chunk? I specified the fields sort name, sort rank ASC. But it did not help. Currently sorting is done by id, which is assigned to the image during loading. Thanks for the help!

small snippet of code

```
[[!Gallery

    &tpl=`albb`

    &sort=`name`

]]
```

Sort name, ASC. Sorting worked alphabetically. It does not suit me. I need to by the number in the file name.

Comment: Have you tried &sort=filename